# How to set selinux?

Tags: selinux

I installed selinux first, I set `SELINUX=enforcing` instead of its original value, `SELINUX=permissive` in `/etc/selinux/config`, then I reboot my computer.

I waited for some time, but it stopped, I rebooted again and it can not go into the system anymore so I restored the setting.

I tried to run `seinfo` command in a terminal, but it output some errors below:

```
ERROR: policydb version 26 does not match my version range 15-24
ERROR: Unable to open policy /etc/selinux/ubuntu/policy/policy.26.
ERROR: Input/output error
```

It seems that there is a little difference on how to start up selinux between CentOS and Ubuntu, can you help me configure selinux in Ubuntu?

Comment: When you say "I installed selinux", can you explain what exactly did you install ( ie, what packages exactly ) ?